# How can I explicitly link to the `index.html` file in a Quarto Book

Tags: r, bookdown, quarto

I'm used to using `bookdown` to create books that don't have to be hosted on a webserver to work properly. I usually keep the `_book` directory and make it available on a shared drive with my team so that when my users click a link from somewhere else, they are taken into the book that lives on the OS file system.

With quarto, just about everything works similar to `bookdown` in this regard. However, when I try to navigate to the `index.html` landing page, it seems that quarto is expecting this to live on a webserver so the links don't go to `book-name/index.html`, they instead go to `book-name/`. Which throws an error when I'm using this in the file system.

Is there a way to ensure the link to the index page in my table of contents explicitly refers to `book-name/index.html`?

Here is the link that appears when I hover over the bookdown index link in the table of contents.

[image: bookdown index]

Here is the link that appears when I hover over the quarto index link in the table of contents.

[image: quarto index]

But everything else in quarto links explicitly to the page it needs.

[image: quarto chapter]

Answer (score 4):

Also stumbled across this one. I don't think it's desired behavior. Solved it by setting the link manually in the sidebar.

Simply add the following key to `book:` in the `_book.yml` file:

```
book:
  .
  .
  sidebar:
    title: "<a href='/index.html'>Your Book Title</a>"
```